# Finding all maching words to a pattern

Tags: algorithm

I receive a word, and some of the letter are missing. I meed to return all the possible matching words to this pattern.
For example I receive `__erf_ow` I need to return `overflow`

If I get pattern `_a_` I need to return :`cat` `bag` ... all the words that are in length 3 and the second letter is a

Given a dictionary of all the words - what is the best way to store it ,or which algorithm to use in order to fast finding all the relevant words?

**Edit**: By best I mean run time. I don't care how much time it's take to store the data (as long it's finish), but I want to give fast answer. the obvious answer will be hash table, but this table will be to big .

Comment: "Best"? Interesting question. My opinion is that the best would be a finite state transducer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer).

Comment: How about simply using regular expressions? pattern being the received word and the dictionary being the text corpus ?

Comment: _(...), but this table will be to big_. I don't think it's a real problem: [The Oxford English Dictionary, 2nd edition (OED2) includes over 600,000 definitions, following a rather inclusive policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language#Number_of_words_in_English).

Comment: @AlexFilipovici - maybe I didn't understand what is the key of the hash table ? the word ? the pattern  ?

Comment: Are patterns like `________` (matching `overflow`, `superman`, `anything`, ...) possible/likely?

Comment: @mbratch If you mean have the pattern be an FST, that doesn't really cut down on the running time - you still have to search through everything. If you mean make an FST of all the words, how will you handle the `_`? You have to explore practically the whole thing for something like `_______________z`, because you have to process the input left to right (or really in any order, but the order has to be consistent for each search), no?

Comment: @anatolyg it is possible but not likely  ...

Comment: @AlexFilipovici For the pattern as a key in a hash table, there are theoretically `27^maxWordLength` possibilities (obviously won't be that many, but you'll have to reduce that **a lot** to get to an amount that will fit in memory). And each word will be have `2^wordLength` references to it.

Comment: From what I understood, the dictionary is already given. Let's suppose it's `{"ab", "ac", "bc"}`. The hash table should contain as keys only the following masks: `{"__", "a_", "b_", "_b", "_c"}`. You may notice that we don't need `{"c_","ab_" etc}` in the hash table, as this values resolve to inexisting words (in the scope of our dictionary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Best' depends on the resources you have.

Here is what I would do:

1. Store a separate dictionary for each word length.
2. I assume your search is not case sensitive!
   Store for each word a 32-bit value in which the bits 0 to 25 are set if the character `a..z` occurs in the word. 
   Store the words in a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` (key is the 32-bit value, value is a list of all words for this key)

How to search:

1. Take the dictionary with the words of the wanted length
2. Create the 32-bit value for your pattern.
3. Iterate all keys of the `Map` and check if the key bitwise and with the 32-bit value for your pattern is equal to the 32-bit value for your pattern. If not this cannot be matches.
   If this check is passed, it is not sufficient to be a match, because it does not handle order of characters or if the occur more than ones. But the check is very fast and does not need to look at each character of the words.
4. Iterate the list in the `Map` and check them which are real matches for your pattern by comparing the characters of each word in the list with your pattern.

Example:
Dictionary for 3-letter words:
the, cat, bag, nor, ega, atc, ron;

```
-> Hashvalues
     00000000000010000000000010010000   the
     00000000000010000000000000000101   cat, atc
     00000000000000000000000001000011   bag
     00000000000000100110000000000000   nor, ron
     00000000000000000000000001010001   age, ega

 Value for pattern _a_ is 00000000000000000000000000000001

Step 3 returns that the keys 
      00000000000010000000000000000101,  
      00000000000000000000000001000011 and 
      00000000000000000000000001010001 are candidates for matches.



Step 4 returns: 'cat' and 'bag'
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. the key in the hash is not very usable, for `_a_` only the first bit will be on , so the key will be `1`, but all the others have some other key - like `cat` which have the 1,3,20 bits on have other key.

Comment: Sorry, I also found out that this did not full solved the problem -> I improved my answer.

Comment: Great ! now it's correct. but as for run time you will have to run: numberOfWordInLenghtN*Number of expose letters.

Comment: For the runtime the idea is: 1. for big dictionaries (and longer words) the key-set is a lot smaller than numberOfWordInLenghtN because a lot share the same key. 2. comparing the keys is much faster and independent of the length of the words (it is simply *one* int bit operation `&` and a int '==' compare which are very fast).

Comment: You got my vote, but I leave it open to see if there is a faster run time

Answer (score 0):

If you use a HashMap, in which you sort by letters, it will seem smaller?

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<Character, ArrayList<String>>> dictionary;
```

The first character of your HashMap is the indicator, which letter is part of the word.

The first ArrayList could store every word, the index of the List could show, what Character is stored where. So you can get words with -a-: dictionary.get(2).get(a). Results: Every word with a, second place.

The second ArrayList stores the words.

Comment: How do you search that for `_a_`?

Comment: The Map only links differnent Arraylists, so you have a lot of small lists.

Comment: Jan, do a for-loop and get every word in your chosen list. Then check every String by doing `string.charAt(2);`

Comment: How do you choose a list? If there is only a list for each starting character, you'll have to search through all of the data if you're not given the first letter, which doesn't really help much.

Comment: Okay, seems legit. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) could help you. There are other string similarity functions. You could work on your own distance functions given your constraints. Also, the transducer is a good idea. [Here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)'s a good start to work on this idea, again, you will have to work on making this fit your own problem.

If as Dukeling says below you need to cut your runtime, then you may be able to do this using some compact data structures like a wavelet tree, and do access/range/rank queries over the nodes (best case being a log2 of the size of the alphabet), but again, you will have to make it fit your own problem.

Comment: A string similarity function doesn't really help. Checking whether any given word matches a pattern is no problem (actually string similarity will just complicate thing unnecessarily), the problem is reducing the search space as to not have an O(n) search, which string similarity does not address.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind being very un-efficient memory wise, you can store sets of words in hash table - where the key are the patterns (I believe this should be one of the fastest algorithms for getting the data):

```
trees = {}


def init(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for word in f:
            word = word.strip()
            s = trees.get((len(word),0,''), set())
            s.add(word)
            trees[(len(word),0,'')] = s
            for i,c in enumerate(word):
                s = trees.get((len(word),i,c), set())
                s.add(word)
                trees[(len(word),i,c)] = s


def words_for_pattern(pattern):
    pattern = pattern.lower()
    words = trees[(len(pattern),0,'')]
    for i, c in enumerate(pattern):
        if c in "abcddefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            words = words.intersection(trees[(len(pattern),i,c)])

    return words

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init('english-words.20')
    while (True):
        pattern = raw_input("Enter pattern: ")
        print words_for_pattern(pattern)


 Enter pattern: **ll*
>>> set(['balls', 'rolls', 'hills', 'cells', 'polls', 'jelly', 'bills', 'pills', 'jolly', 'halls', 'bells'])
```

Here `trees` is a map where the keys are 3-tuples: `(word-length, character index, character)` and each key's value is a set of all the words with length of `word-length` and with `character` in the `character index` place. In addition there are special keys that contains all the words of certain length.

When getting the words for a pattern I intersect the sets of words for each non-blank character in the pattern.

Comment: the problem this way, is that you have very bug table. `2^(average word lenght)` which I think is not acceptable.